# phpmyadmin stuck in login page with no messages (ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm stuck in phpmyadmin login page, it worked fine yesterday

after insert username and password, login page displayed again and again with no messages.

[image]

Comment: Can you give your url after username and password and press GO button

Comment: it return again to login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it (there is no enough storage space on the server)

thanks,